# Undefined this.$overflowTabBtn.data(...) initTabs Craft.js:11326:51

Tags: craft3, javascript, plugin-solspacecalendar, editing

I'm getting this error on one Solspace calendar (2.x) event entry form, but not another. The only difference seems to be two asset fields, and one entry reference field. It's the only page the error occurs, and it just cropped up after the 3.4 update.

```
TypeError: this.$overflowTabBtn.data(...) is undefined in
    initTabs Craft.js:11326:51
```

Update 2020/02/24:
I confirmed that it was a conflict with the Craft 3.4 update and entry, and asset, reference fields on an event.

Comment: I suggest you to open a support ticket for that kind of bug: https://docs.solspace.com/craft/freeform/v3/support.html#create-a-support-ticket

Comment: The Solspace Calendar 3.x branch doesn't conflict with Craft 3.4.